# ClassicThesis : Add document title to every page

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I'm using classicthesis package to write a user manual. Using `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` I got the classical header layout as below:[image: actual header layout]. 
I would like instead to customize my header in every page adding manual title as below.[image: desired layout]
Some suggestion to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Try `\ihead{MY BOOK TITLE}` or `\ihead*{MY BOOK TITLE}`. With the starred version the manuel title should appear on pages with pagestyle `plain` too (e.g. chapter pages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classicthesis` loads package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Therefore the default page style is `scrheadings`. So you can use

```
\ihead{MY BOOK TITLE}
```

or

```
\ihead*{MY BOOK TITLE}
```

With the starred version this text appears also on pages using page style `plain`, e.g. chapter pages.